# Using variables in SQL Statment

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-server-2016

I'm using Microsoft Access 2016 forms with SQL Server 2018, and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.4

Already I have :

```
UPDATE Student SET NAME = 'PRATIK' WHERE Age = 20;
```

It is OK.

When I define `AA` & `BB` as below :

```
Dim AA as integer
Dim AA as string

AA = 20 
BB = 'PATRIK'
```

And run as:

```
UPDATE Student SET NAME = BB WHERE Age = AA;
```

Error message said:

> Invalid column Name 'BB' and 'AA'

I dont need data entry directly work on server to write `AA` and `BB` value (`20`, `PATRIK`).

I tried define as `@AA=20`, `@bb='PATRIK'` but Access 2016 forms reject of using `Prefix@`.

Comment: The variables are defined in VBA code. The update statement is sql code. It is not the same. Do you want VBA code?

Answer (score 2):

You must concatenate the variables:

```
SQL = "UPDATE Student SET [NAME] = '" & BB & "' WHERE Age = " & AA & ";"
CurrentDb.Execute SQL
```

or create a query with parameters and set the parameter values.

Comment: Concatenating with concern for single quotes around strings is a significant barrier to entry for new users.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something along the lines of:

```vb
Dim AA As Integer
Dim BB As String

AA = 20
BB = "PATRIK"

With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", "update Student t set t.name = @name where t.age = @age")
    .Parameters(0) = BB
    .Parameters(1) = AA
    .Execute
End With
```

Using parameters in this way avoids the need to worry about formatting data types within the SQL statement and also avoids any potential for SQL injection.